# How to get all objects in a module in python?

Tags: python, module

I need to get a list of all the objects within a module -- not a list of just their names. So, for instance, I have:

```
class myClass:  
    def __init__(self):  
        # here be code
        pass

class thing1(myClass):  
    def __init__(self):  
        self.x = 1

class thing2(myClass):  
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 2
```

and so on.

What I want is something that will give me a list of the objects in `myClass` (`thing1`, `thing2`) from which I can call methods / get attributes. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
for myThing in dir(myClass):  
    print myThing.x
```

But the `dir` function only gives a list of the names of the classes, and I can't get the attribute from that.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you have the name of an attribute in a string, you should use `getattr` to fetch it out.

Given a module X, you can get a list of all it's attributes and (for example) their types with something like this.

```
for i in dir(X):
   print (i,"  ",type(getattr(X,i)))
```

Answer (score 9):

If you actually want the *members* of a class, instance or module, just use the `vars()` builtin: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars (it works as advertised)

If you want the members of the *current* module from within a function or class (where `vars()` will do the wrong thing) then you should use `globals()` instead.

However, the code and the words in your question don't match. You *say* you want access to the objects "within" `myClass`, but then you post code that is apparently looking for the subclasses of `myClass` rather than its contents.

To supplement Asterisk's answers with some more examples of playing with this at the interactive prompt:

```
>>> class Example:
...   def method(): pass
...
>>> class SubExample(Example):
...   pass
...
>>> class OverrideExample(Example):
...   def method():
...     pass
...
>>> globals()
{'OverrideExample': <class '__main__.OverrideExample'>, '__builtins__': <module
'builtins' (built-in)>, 'Example': <class '__main__.Example'>, '__name__': '__ma
in__', '__package__': None, '__doc__': None, 'SubExample': <class '__main__.SubE
xample'>}
>>> Example.__subclasses__()
[<class '__main__.SubExample'>, <class '__main__.OverrideExample'>]
>>> vars(Example)
dict_proxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Example' objects>, '__module__
': '__main__', '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Example' objects>, 'm
ethod': <function method at 0x00BF6F18>, '__doc__': None})
>>> vars(SubExample)
dict_proxy({'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None})
>>> vars(OverrideExample)
dict_proxy({'__module__': '__main__', 'method': <function method at 0x00C10030>,
 '__doc__': None})
>>> vars(Example())
{}
>>> vars(SubExample())
{}
>>> vars(OverrideExample())
{}
```

Note the differences between what is visible at the module level, on each class object and on each class instance.

Also note that, for a given class definition, `vars()` *won't* tell you about any inherited methods. It also won't tell you about methods that are available via a class instance. To correctly see both of those, your best bet is to do as Noufal suggests and walk `dir()`, calling `getattr()` for each attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `locals()` gives you a dictionary of all the local variables and the objects they are pointing to.

You could also try using the `eval()` or `exec()` functions to evaluate the names as raw python code.  Then you could directly use the results from `dir()`.

Comment: How do you use eval() or exec() to evaluate 'myThing'.x?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that helps:

```
class myClass(object):

    def init(self):
        pass


class thing1(myClass):
    def init(self):
        self.x = 1

class thing2(myClass):
    def init(self):
        self.x = 2

myClass.__subclasses__()
[<class '__main__.thing1'>, <class '__main__.thing2'>]
```

Comment: so this gives you the classes, but how do you get self.x from one of the classes?

Comment: posted another answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
class myClass(object):

    def init(self):
        pass


class thing1(myClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

class thing2(myClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 2

print myClass.__subclasses__()
print vars(thing1())
print vars(thing2())
```

---

```
[<class '__main__.thing1'>, <class '__main__.thing2'>]
{'x': 1}
{'x': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way to list modules is:

```
from <module> import *
print dir(<module>)
```